# Is there a better solution (?)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

There are two sequences $ a_n  $ and $ b_n $, which fulfill 3 certain properties:

The series of one of them converges, while the other diverges.

$ \frac {a_n} {b_n} $ = 1, if n tends to infinity.

$ b_n \neq  0 $ for all n;

I think I have found a solution for this problem and I hope I am not violating any rule:

(edit: incorrect!)

The sequences are of the form:

$ a_{n+1} = - a_n + (a_n + \frac 1 {n+1} ) ; a_n $ converges as a sequence and as a series, let's say to $ a \neq 0 $; 
The other one converges monotonously to $a $ as a  sequence, thus the series diverges.
I dislike my definition of the sequence a_n, so I wondered, if there is another, better solution to this problem.

Comment: Are you sure your recurrence for $ a_n $ is correct?  I've never seen the notation $1_{n+1} $ before.

Comment: Isn't this limit comparison test?

Comment: problems fixed with the notation, now it should be correct @ anorton; and thx for pointing it out

Comment: $\sum a_{n}$ looks divergent to me.

Comment: Unless I'm reading it wrong, the $a_n$'s just cancel out to leave $\frac{1}{n+1}$ which doesn't converge. With that being said, couldn't you just pick any convergent sequence (e.g. $\frac{1}{x^2}$, and then set your other sequence to the reciprocal of that, to solve this problem?

Comment: ok, i see now that my "solution" doesn't work.

Comment: @mardat $a_{n}/(1/a_{n}) = a_{n}^{2}$. Your example if it worked as you wanted would contradict the limit comparison test.

Comment: Try $\displaystyle a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $\displaystyle b_n=a_n(1+a_n)=a_n+\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: ah thank you! Those sequences do the job and the solution looks neat!